# Как с помощью jQuery получить данные заключенные в элементе SPAN?

Tags: jquery

Допустим есть такая конструкция:

```
<span id="smth">Текст</span>
```

Как получить содержимое ("Текст")?

Comment: Эм... Поправьте пожалуйста код, там SPAN стоит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery: `$('#smth').html()`
plain js: `document.getElementById('smth').innerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

```
$("span#smth").text();
```